# Please help me with this problem of double exponential distribution

Tags: stochastic-calculus

please help me with this problem of double exponential distribution[image]

Comment: Hi sir, its in my assignment of stochastic calculus.

Comment: I am following Stochastic calculus for finance 2 by steven shreve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f_X(x) > 0$ and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx = 1,
\end{align*}
$f_X(x)$ is a valid density function.

Let
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
\end{align*}
be the density function of a standard normal random variable. We define the measure $\widetilde{P}$ using the Randon-Nykodim derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\widetilde{P}}{dP} = \frac{\varphi(X)}{f_X(X)}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{P}(X \leq x) &= E_{\widetilde{P}}(1_{X \le x})\\
&=E_P\left(\frac{d\widetilde{P}}{dP} 1_{X \le x} \right)\\
&=E_P\left(\frac{\varphi(X)}{f_X(X)} 1_{X \le x} \right)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\varphi(x)}{f_X(x)} f_X(x) dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x \varphi(x) dx.
\end{align*}
That is, $X$ is standard normal w.r.t. the measure $\widetilde{P}$.

The equivalence follows, since
\begin{align*}
\frac{dP}{d\widetilde{P}} = \frac{f_X(X)}{\varphi(X)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Its really helpful in understanding the concept.